# Using one label for two input box,Input boxes not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to design like this image in contact from 7 in wordpress. I've tried but can't understand my mistake.

[image]

my code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0;">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding:0;">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Name:</label><span style="color:red;" class:col-sm-1>*</span>
      [text* your-name id:Name class:very-special-field-for-checkbox class:form-control placeholder "First Name"]
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.col -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
<label ></label>
     [text* your-name id:Name class:form-control placeholder "Last Name"]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this fiddle,
Bootstrap-4 row uses flexbox and "flex-wrap" property is set to "wrap" by default.
You make it "nowrap".
https://jsfiddle.net/f2tkexrL/21/

```css
.row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin:0;">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding:0;">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label><span style="color:red;" class:col-sm-1>*</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
          <input type="text">
          <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
          <input type="text">
          <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .how to add validation test on to the top of *?After submitting the form text will be seen.how to do this?i tried but this validation text seems under text box.

Comment: if name is required, you need to use "required" attribute in both of input fields.
like this,
   <input required type="text">